# Independence implies equality

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In a paper I am reading:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent positive and non-degenerate random variables. Also let $S=X+Y$ and $R={X\over S}.$ If $R$ and $S$ are independent then:
$$f_{R,S}({x\over{x+y}},x+y)=f_R({x\over{x+y}})f_S(x+y)=(x+y)f_X(x)f_Y(y).$$ Where $f$ is the density function.

How did we get the last equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second equality doesn't actually rely on the independence of $R$ and $S$. Consider the following functions:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
r\\
s
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{x}{x+y}\\
x+y
\end{pmatrix}:=
G\left(\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}\right).$$

Notice that this function is invertible, and its inverse is differentiable:

$$H\left(\begin{pmatrix}
r\\
s
\end{pmatrix}\right):= G^{-1}\left(\begin{pmatrix}
r\\
s
\end{pmatrix}\right) = \begin{pmatrix}
rs\\
s-rs
\end{pmatrix}.$$

So now we just apply a change of variable to $r = \frac{x}{x+y}$ and $s = x+y$:

\begin{align*}
f_{R,S}\left(\frac{x}{x+y},x+y\right)&=f_{R,S}(r,s)\\
&= f_{X,Y}(x,y)\left|\det\frac{d(x,y)}{d(r,s)}\right|\\
&= f_X(x)f_Y(y)\begin{vmatrix}s&r\\-s&1-r\end{vmatrix}\\
&= f_X(x)f_Y(y)\left(s - sr + sr\right)\\
&=(x+y)f_X(x)f_Y(y).
\end{align*}